# Prove or disprove that there exist $x_{i}$ such $\frac{\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^{n}(x_{i}-x_{j})}{(n-1)!}\in Z$

Tags: number-theory

**conjecture**：

> for any integers $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$, there exist a integer $x_{i}(i\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\})$ such
>   $$\dfrac{\displaystyle \prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^{n}(x_{i}-x_{j})}{(n-1)!}\in Z$$

The seemingly obvious conclusion, seemingly not proof, of course, the problem may not be correct

it seem  relate to this problem, .:[Direct proof of Gelfand-Zetlin identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/direct-proof-of-gelfand-zetlin-)  and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422294/prove-that-a-given-expression-is-always-an-integer?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085531/how-prove-this-prod-1-le-ij-le-n-fraca-j-a-ij-i-is-integer?noredirect=1&lq=1)identity but they are stronger than this one

Comment: Which $i$ do you use for the "$x_i$" in the product?  (It's not an index of the product...)

Comment: Did you try doing the first several cases to see if a pattern emerges?

Comment: sorry,I have edit it.

Comment: Probably won't help but kind of related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257502/link-between-two-products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $n=5$ and $\{x_1,\cdots,x_5\}=\{1,2,4,6,7\}$, and let $P_i=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\prod_{j\neq i}(x_j-x_i)$. Then

\begin{align*}
P_1 &= \frac{1\times3\times5\times6}{4!} = \frac{15}{4}, \\
P_2 &= \frac{(-1)\times2\times4\times5}{4!} = -\frac{5}{3}, \\
P_3 &= \frac{(-3)\times(-2)\times2\times3}{4!} = \frac{3}{2}, \\
P_4 &= \frac{(-5)\times(-4)\times(-2)\times1}{4!} = -\frac{5}{3}, \\
P_5 &= \frac{(-6)\times(-5)\times(-3)\times(-1)}{4!} = \frac{15}{4}
\end{align*}

---

The claim is true when $n \leq 4$. Since it is almost clear when $n \leq 3$, we prove the claim for $n=4$.

Let $x_1,\cdots,x_4$ be arbitrary integers. By the pigeonhole principle, there exist $a, b \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ such $a \neq b$ and $x_a \equiv x_b \text{ (mod 3)}$. Now

- If $x_a \equiv x_b \text{ (mod 2)}$, then $x_b - x_a$ is a multiple of $6$.
- If $x_a \not\equiv x_b \text{ (mod 2)} $, then for any $j \in \{1,2,3,4\}\setminus\{a,b\}$ either $x_j - x_a$ or $x_j - x_b$ is even.

In both cases, either $\prod_{j\neq a} (x_j-x_a)$ or $\prod_{j\neq b} (x_j-x_b)$ is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: Thanks,It's nice.can you find the $n=4?$ ,it is easy to show $n=3$ my conjecture is holde

Comment: @functionsug, That is an interesting question, and although I have no proof, my gut is telling that it should hold for $n=4$ as both $2$ and $3$ are prime. I am trying some pigeonhole argument, so let me see if I can actually come up with anything. (But I am quite bad at numver theory, so I may end up with nothing... :s) Oh, and just for your information, I made amend of my previous answer on $H(a_i)$'s a couple of hours ago.

Comment: @sangechul Lee Thanks ,I have see it, maybe it's $n=4$ is right and I think it's interesring question